# Choose available memory for containers in Rancher

Tags: memory, docker, rancher

In rancher, how do I choose the available memory for a docker container?
On OSX, I can do like so:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm default --memory 5000
```

To define the memory available to my docker-machine. How would I achieve this using rancher to set up a host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're adding hosts in a cloud provider (EC2, DigitalOcean, etc) through the Add Host UI then they all have some sort of size option for offering, flavor, RAM, etc depending on the specific provider and their terminology.

Containers themselves have no memory limit by default in Docker. They can use any memory available in the host, and they do not "reserve"any of it so it is all held by a particular container like when you deploy a VM.

There is an option to limit how much memory (+ swap) a container is allowed to use, which is in the Host/Security tab of the service/container definition.

Comment: This sounds correct, and my experience when launching containers on an Ubuntu server through EC2 was exactly that the container was only limited by the host memory and no memory needed to be upfront allocated.